# How to get top 10 record by its score field

Tags: database, linq

I'm working on a project which there are shop's and customer's.customer's can score shop's.

my Score Data Table is like this:

Table Name is:ShopScores

[image]

I want to retrieve top 10 shops based on their Score field result.Is it possible to do that and if the answer is Yes, How can I do it?

By the way, I want to do that using LINQ Query.

Comment: No,because I don't know how to find the biggest score in the  Score field.

Comment: select (top 10)  * from ShopScores Order by Score desc something like that

Comment: oops didnt read last line, however in linq its take(10) on your select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `linq`:

```
var result = Context.ShopScores.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Score).Take(10);
```

Comment: That's nice,Thanks @Giorgi Nakeuri

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `ShopScores` ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 10
```

this gives the records ordered by score ,but this is for mysql
This works perfectly fine

Comment: what if more than one customer have given score to the same shop ?

Comment: ignore this because the use of lint is mentioned in below answer

Comment: I just need to get top 10 shops on their scores.just the scores are important.